# PHP Imap - Character not allowed in mailbox name: '.'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, imap

I try to move an email from Drafts to Sent directory.

I use the imap_mail_move method :

```
imap_mail_move($imapStream, $mailId, $mailBox, CP_UID);
```

$imapStream is the imap stream of Drafts directory

$mailBox = {imapserver}Sent

The imap_mail_move method return false

and imap_errors() return :

```
array:2 [
   0 => "Character not allowed in mailbox name: '.'"
   1 => "Character not allowed in mailbox name: '.'"
]
```

imap_list() method return :

```
array:41 [
   28 => "{imapserver}Sent"
   ...
   31 => "{imapserver}Drafts"
   ....
   40 => "{imapserver}INBOX"
]
```

Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: What is `$mailBox` ?

Comment: `$mailBox = "{imapserver}Sent"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is quite clear, you cannot use a dot `.` in the mailbox' name.

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-mail-move.php), `$mailBox` does not need the server's name in it. Just use `INBOX/Sent` or `Sent`, depending on which folder you want.

Comment: Thank you, i was lost in my problem, i turned round without seeing the problem was so simple